# Object Oriented PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
class Box {
    var $contents;

    function Box($contents) {
        $this-&gt;contents = $contents;
    }

    function get_whats_inside() {
        return $this-&gt;contents;
    }
}
?>
```

I am going through a OO tutorial. I am familiar with PHP and the concept of OO but it is still an uphill struggle most of the time! However, the code above returns the error "Unexpected & on line 7". I cannot find anyone else having had problems with the tutorial. I am running MAMP with php version 5.2.5. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should read $this->contents instead of $this-&gt;contents

Comment: I really should learn to actually look at what is in front of me. Doy! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be

```
$this->contents = $contents;
return $this->contents;
```

instead of

```
$this-&gt;contents = $contents;
return $this-&gt;contents;
```

Seems there was some HTML involved...

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your code has been HTML-encoded.

The "& gt;"s should be ">" symbols